# How to pair a Windows 10 phone with PC for debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-mobile

I get a code on my phone - but where do I enter it?

I tried connecting by usb, entering the wifi url into my PC's browser ("insecure connection"),...

Comment: code for **WHAT**? bluetooth?

Comment: The only code available. (after clicking "pair") - Check your phone and see.

Comment: The titile and question do not match and is very unclear. Do you mean how to enable debug on phone? see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development

Comment: How do they not match? I want to connect the two for debugging. I already saw that link before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

Edited (May2016):

With later Win10 mobile its now possible to debug a phone running Windows 10 Mobile via WIFI.
Follow the guidance here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile

Comment: Possible, in theory. In practice, this feature is still broken in Visual Studio 2015 ([Unable to pair Windows 10 Mobile Devices](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2127326/unable-to-pair-windows-10-mobile-devices)). Debugging still requires a USB cable connection, even with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.